# Why is blade displaying the model original value and not attribute?

Tags: laravel-5

In my controller I am mutating the original value of a model like this;

```
$tags = [
 '[firstName]', 
 '[city]'
];

$values = [
 $recipient['firstName'],
 $city['name']
];


$module['content'] = str_replace($tags, $values, $module['content']);
```

Then in blade I am just trying to use the mutated attribute;

```
{!! $module['content'] !!}
```

I can see that my mutation is working when I dd the model but once passed to my view, it is presenting the original value and not the attribute.

Why/how is this?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the full controller code? :)

Comment: What does `$module['content']` look like before the attempted mutation, seems like you may have your keys wrong in `$tags`. (I.e. I'm thinking you need to remove the brackets in $tags, as it would translate to looking for `$module['content'][[firstname]]` and the double brackets would obviously cause an error..